# Writing data into Snowflake from Python with Pandas write_pandas

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I used the following code taken from Snowflake's website:

```
import snowflake.connector
engine = snowflake.connector.connect(
        account="XXX",
        user="SYSADMIN",
        password="XXX",
        role="SYSADMIN",
        warehouse="COMPUTE_WH",
        database="XXX",
        schema="PUBLIC"
    )

pandasDF = pd.DataFrame(rowData)
pandasDF.columns = pandasDF.columns.astype(str)

from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas

success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(engine, pandasDF, 'OI_PNET_GET_PERFORMX_UPL2')
```

Which throws the following error:

```
  Message=000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 100
invalid identifier '"0"'
  Source=C:\Users\Fleet_Manager_PeopleNet.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\Fleet_Manager_PeopleNet.py", line 232, in <module> (Current frame)
    success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(engine, pandasDF, 'OI_PNET_GET_PERFORMX_UPL2')
```

When I look at the Pandas Dataframe it appears to be inserting the row number (starting at 00).  How to I get it to write this XML data into a Snowflake Variant table without the leading 00 before the data column to be inserted?  I have never used a Pandas Dataframe before.

Comment: Can you help us reproduce with the data inside that row and table schema? You mentioned it's a variant and XML?

Comment: It looks your connector is right. Can you try to load any table from Snowflake in order to check if the connector is working properly? pd.read_sql("select * from your_table", engine). Snowlake follows a standard SQL convention and understands double quotes as identifiers for column names, table names and etc. The problem should be there.

Comment: Update:  I got it to insert records into the Variant Table but it inserts quotation marks around the XML data and I can't select anything in Snowflake.  How do I get around this error or remove the quotation marks?  pandasDF = pd.DataFrame(rowData) pandasDF.columns =['DATACOLUMN']  success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(engine, pandasDF, 'OI_PNET_GET_PERFORMX_UPL2')

Comment: I also tried setting the quote_identifers to false but still get double quotes around each row in the Variant Table:  success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(engine, pandasDF, 'OI_PNET_GET_PERFORMX_UPL2', quote_identifiers = False)